# Kotlin + Hilt: Injecting activity context to object class

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, android-context, dagger-hilt

I have an object with many screen related methods (I put only two as an example here) as follows:

```
object AWScreen {

    private lateinit var context: Context

    fun init(context: Context) {
        this.context = context
    }

    private fun getScreenHeightAlternative(oContext: Context): Int {
        val display = oContext.resources.displayMetrics
        return display.heightPixels
    }

    fun getScreenWidth(context: Context?): Int {
        val size = Point()
        var screenWidth = 0
        try {
            (context as Activity).windowManager.defaultDisplay.getRealSize(size)
            screenWidth = size.x
        } catch (e: NoSuchMethodError) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return screenWidth
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to initialise all dependencies (only context in this case) from an Application Class -when app starts- as follows:

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class AWApplication : MultiDexApplication() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        AWScreen.init(this)
    }
}
```

But, as you can see, this way what I get is an application context rather than an activity context (what is needed to access resources).

I could just do:

```
AWScreen.init(this)
```

In any activity that depends on AWScreen onCreate, but I was trying to avoid this as AWScreen is widely used along my app and I don't want to repeat code, and in fact that's what Hilt (dependency injection) is meant for.

In resume, I have many custom classes (objects) where I need an activity context (rather than an application context) to access Resources (or any other class depending on the context), but I don't know how to provide it in a "dependency injection way" using Hilt, and avoiding the need to initialise that object's dependencies in every activity.

Edit 1:

As @مصطفى نعمه mentioned, I can access resources with any context (activity context as well as application context), but in my AWScreen class there are methods like the next:

```
private fun getSoftButtonsBarHeight(oActivity: Activity): Int {
        val metrics = DisplayMetrics()
        oActivity.windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(metrics)
        val usableHeight = metrics.heightPixels
        oActivity.windowManager.defaultDisplay.getRealMetrics(metrics)
        val realHeight = metrics.heightPixels
        return if (realHeight > usableHeight) realHeight - usableHeight else 0
    }
```

where I need to access windowManager, and windowManager is only available in an activity context, so, to be clear, what I need to know is how to inject an activity context into a custom class.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully understand your question but

you can access the resources by the app context normally like this :
after you inject the context ->->

```
val someString = context?.resources.getString(R.string.some_string) //context is nullable so "?" is needed
```

Comment: Hello @مصطفى نعمه, and thanks for your reply. Please read my edit to see if it makes my question clearer for you.